# PHP POST and execute for large file uploads

Tags: php, file, upload

I have the following PHP Files:

- fileUploadForm.php
- handleUpload.php

fileUploadForm contains the following output:

- output $_SESSION['errorMessage'] (if any)
- Output a file upload form that posts to handleUpload.php

handleUpload.php performs the following actions:

- Validates session (redirects to login if validation fails)
- Validates file (sets $_SESSION['errorMessage'] if validation fails)
- Scan File for Virus
- MoveFile
- Update database

The script is having trouble on large file uploads.  I have set all of the php.ini settings regarding file uploads to be ridiculously huge, for testing purposes.  So I don't believe the issue is a configuration issue.

The following behavior is confusing me:

- When I watch the file grow in tmp, the file upload continues well past the max_input_time that was set.  My understanding was that once the max_input_time is exceeded, the script will terminate, and in turn, so would the file upload.  Any thoughts on why this isn't happening?
- if I stop the file upload midstream and refresh fileUploadForm (not resubmit it), the script will output error messages related to file validation that are set in handleUpload.  This seems to indicate that even though the file upload did not complete, lines of code in handleUpload are being executed.  Does php execute a script and receive the form data asynchronously?  I would have thought that the script would wait until all form data was received before executing any code.  But this assumption is contradicted by the behavior I am seeing.  What is the order in which a data POST / script execution occurs?
- When max_input_time, along with the rest of the config values, is set to be ridiculously large for testing, very large uploads will complete.  However, the rest of the script just seems to die.  i.e. the virus scan and file move never happen, nor do the database updates.  I have error handling set for each action in the script, but no errors are thrown.  The page just seems to have died.  Any thoughts on why this might happen / how to catch such an error?

Thanks in advance.
Kate

Answer (score 0):

This quote from your second question answers (at least partially) the other two:

```
I would have thought that the script would wait until all form data was received before executing any code.
```

In order for PHP to be able to handle all input data, Apache (or whatever HTTP server you are using) will first wait for the file upload to be complete and only after that it will process the PHP script. So, PHP's `max_input_time` check will come into play after the file upload process is completed.

Now, in that case you'd probably ask then why your virus scanning, file moving and any other script procedures don't happen, since it's logical that any time counter related to PHP should start with the script's execution and this should happen after all input data is received. Well, that SHOULD be the case and to be honest - my thoughts on this are a kind of shot in the dark, but well ... either some other limit is exceeded or the script is started with the request, but is being suspended by the httpd until ready to proceed with it and effectively - some of those counters might expire during this time.

I don't know how to answer your second question as a refresh would mean that all of the data is re-POST-ed and should be re-processed. I doubt that you'd do the other thing - simply loading handleUpload.php without re-submitting the form, but it's a possibility that I should mention. A secound guess would be that if the first request was terminated unexpectedly - some garbage collection and/or recovery process happens the second time.

Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: I'm only refreshing fileUploadForm.php, and not actually resubmitting it.  But it now contains session info that was set in handleUpload.  So, some of the code is being executed.  And it is being executed before the entire file is uploaded to tmp.

Comment: The PHP docs seem inconsistent on how this happens.  It defines max_input_time as you do in the first part of your answer:  "the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST and GET. It is measured from the moment of RECEIVING ALL data on the server to the start of script execution" (ie the count starts AFTER the upload completes). But in a trouble-shooting section it indicates that if max_input_time is not high enough, some file uploads won't complete.  But either way, I see the file upload continue, SOME script execution taking place, and then it fails.

Comment: The question is what do you mean by "only refreshing" - do you go to your browser's address bar and hit Enter or do you press F5(or click Refresh)? If the second is what you do, then the browser would ask you if you want to re-submit the form data and not allow you to continue unless you confirm. If you do the first thing, well ... it's perfectly normal that only session data exists.

Comment: @ Narf I am not resubmitting the form.  I am loading fileUploadForm, NOT handleFileUpload.  What is unusual about the session data existing is that it was set in the handleUpload file at lines that should not have been executed if php is processed synchronously and the file upload / POST wasn't yet complete.  ie, I'm trying to understand why the script is failing and why it fails WHERE it fails (sometime after the validation code)